# help with changing arrays into individual variables in Java

Tags: java, arrays, variables

Please help.

I want to add these option, where goodMan and purchase either a bat, axe or sword to fight the monster.

How do i create these 3 arrays then get the individual variable from them. Then use these variable to affect the outcome of the game?

1. Bat min damage = 2 max damage = 4 cost = 3
2. axe min damage = 4 max damage = 6 cost = 6
3. sword min damage = 6 max damage = 8 cost = 10
4. cancel

```
public static void main(String[] args)
        throws IOException
        {



            int count = 1;

    // start both with 1 point  
    int goodTotal = 50;
    int monTotal = 50;
    int moneyAmt = 10;

     // input switch statement




    loop: while (goodTotal > 0 && monTotal > 0) {


        System.out.print("Type a letter: ");
        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.print("F: Go out and Fight ");
        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.print("R: Rest ");
        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.print("C: Check Stats ");
        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.print("Q: Quit ");
        char input = (char) System.in.read();


        System.out.println("You typed: " + (char)input);         

            switch(input) {
            case 'f': System.out.println("Continue the game"); continue;

            case 'r': System.out.println("Players should rest"); break loop;

            case 'c': System.out.println("Checking the status of the game");
                        System.out.print("Goodman has " + goodTotal + " points and Monster has  " + monTotal + " points");
                         System.out.println("\n"); break loop;

            case 'q': System.out.println("Game over");
            System.exit(input); break loop;

            default: System.out.println("Invalid selection");break;
            }                          


        // Set value of minimum and maximum damage
        int minDmg = 2;
        int maxDmg = 15;

        // Get random number;
        int damage = minDmg + Double.valueOf(Math.random() * (maxDmg - minDmg)).intValue();
        int damage2 = minDmg + Double.valueOf(Math.random() * (maxDmg - minDmg)).intValue();

        // remove value of damage from started value to get total value remaining
        goodTotal = goodTotal - damage;
        monTotal = monTotal - damage2;


        // print message if still in the game
        if(goodTotal > 0){
        System.out.println("Goodman has " + goodTotal + " points left. Not bad, Man! ");
        }

        // if Goodman survives round 2 print a message of encouragement
        if (goodTotal > 0 && count > 1 && count <= 2){
            System.out.print("This is encouraging. Goodman has lasted past roundhh " +count+ ". ");

       // print new message if Goodman passes round 3
        } else if (goodTotal > 0 && count == 3){
            System.out.print("Goodman is as strong as Samson. He has lasted round " +count+ " and still looks strong.");
            System.out.print(" 10 hit points has been added to your total");
            }


        if(monTotal > 0){     
          System.out.println("Wait, Monster has a total of " + monTotal + " points and is still in the game");
        }


         // exit if have less than 0 point, and print game over. Congratulate the winner
       if(goodTotal < 0){
          System.out.println("Goodman you are out of the game");  
          System.out.println("The monster will take over the village. This is sad");
          System.out.println("Game Over!");
          }  else if(monTotal < 0){
          System.out.println("Goodman has been victorious");  
          System.out.println("The monster is dead. The people live!!!!");
          System.out.println("Game Over!");
        }
      System.out.println("This is the end of round " + count +" ");
      System.out.println("\n");
      count = count + 1;

        }

    }
```

Comment: could you try and clarify your question? why do you need arrays for these "objects"?

Comment: As said before, your question is not that clear. Could you explain your problem more precisely? How do you plan to use those arrays?

Comment: I wanted to store these variables as arrays. I do not really understand the concept of arrays but it was required on this project. So i want to declare the arrays, then extract the variable to be used in the rest of the statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got bored tonight and programmed the Fight myself. It's not perfectly modelled, but should provide a good base, to extend.

---

**Main**

```
package stackoverflow.fight;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.Console;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
/**
 * this class runs the fight.
 * 
 * It only deals with the input handling, all the rest is done in Fight.class
 */
public class Main {
    private static enum Command {
    F, // fight
    R, // rest
    B, // buy weapon
    C, // status
    Q, // quit
    UNDEFINED;
}

public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {


    // create the opponents:
    final Opponent goodman = new Opponent("Goodman", 50, false);
    final Opponent monster = new Opponent("Monster", 50, true);

    // and init the fight
    final Fight fight = new Fight(goodman, monster);

    // input switch statement
    // loop while both are alive
    while (fight.isOngoing()) {

        System.out.println("\n" + fight.getTitle());
        System.out.println("\tF: Go out and Fight");
        System.out.println("\tB: Buy Weapon");
        System.out.println("\tR: Rest");
        System.out.println("\tC: Check Stats");
        System.out.println("\tQ: Quit");

        switch (readCommand()) {
        case F:
            System.out.println("f: Continue the fight");
            fight.fight();
            if (!fight.isOngoing()) {
                fight.end();
            }
            break;
        case R:
            fight.rest();

            break;

        case C:
            System.out.println("c: Fight-Status:");
            fight.status();
            break;

        case B:
            System.out.println("b: Buy Weapon:");
            System.out.println(Weapon.getBuyableWeapons());
            Weapon weapon = readWeapon();
            fight.buy(goodman, weapon);
            break;

        case Q:
            System.out.println("q: You quit: Game over");
            System.exit(0);
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("--> Invalid selection");
            break;
        }

    }

}

private static String readLine(String message) throws IOException {
    System.out.print("> "+ message.trim() +": ");
    // readline from System.in
    final String line =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)).readLine();
    if (line == null || "".equals(line.trim())) {
        return readLine(message);
    }
    return line;
}

private static Weapon readWeapon() throws IOException {
    Weapon weapon = Weapon.findByName(readLine("\tChoose your Weapon"));
    if (weapon == null) {
        readWeapon();
    }
    return weapon;
}

private static Command readCommand() throws IOException {

    // transform to Command
    try {
        return Command.valueOf(readLine("Your Comand").toUpperCase());
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        // if command is null, empty or not one of F,R,C or Q
        return readCommand(); // No match ... re-read 
    }
}}
```

---

**Opponent**

```
package stackoverflow.fight;

/**
 * modelling the Fighters
 */
public class Opponent {

private final String name;
private final int maxHitpoints;
private int currentHitpoints;
private Weapon weapon;
private final boolean isMonster;
private int currentMoney;

/**
 * init the fighter
 * 
 * @param name
 * @param maxHitpoints
 *            - starting hitpoints
 * @param isMonster
 *            - true for monster, false for goodman
 */
public Opponent(String name, int maxHitpoints, boolean isMonster) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.maxHitpoints = maxHitpoints;
    this.isMonster = isMonster;
    this.currentHitpoints = this.maxHitpoints; // currentHitpoints will
                                                // decrease with hit

    // Goodman starts with BAT, MOnster uses Claws
    weapon = isMonster ? Weapon.CLAWS : Weapon.BAT;

    // Monster has no money, Goodman starts with 10
    currentMoney = isMonster ? 0 : 10;
}

/**
 * @return the weapon the fighter uses
 */
public Weapon getWeapon() {
    return weapon;
}

/**
 * @param weapon
 */
public void setWeapon(Weapon weapon) {
    if (this.weapon == weapon) {
        return;
    }

    this.weapon = weapon;
    this.currentMoney -= weapon.getCost();

    System.out.println("\t" + name + " bought new weapon " + weapon.getName() + ". Money left: " + currentMoney);
}

/**
 * @return name of the fighter
 */
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

/**
 * @return actual state
 */
public int getCurrentHitpoints() {
    return currentHitpoints;
}



/**
 * runs an attack with current weapon on the opponent
 * 
 * @param opponent
 * @return the damage done
 */
public void attack(Opponent opponent) {
    // one can only attack while he's not dead! (giving an advantage to the first striker)
    if (isAlive()) {
        // calculate the damage
        int damage = weapon.rollDamage();

        opponent.wound(damage);
        // output the dramatic scene
        System.out.println("\t" + name + " attacks " + opponent.getName() + " with " + weapon.getName() 
                + " and deals " + damage + " points of damage, leaving " + opponent.getCurrentHitpoints());
    } else {
        System.out.println("\t" + name + " would strike but unfortunately died trying!");
    }
}

/**
 * reduce currentHitpoints by damage
 * 
 * @param damage
 */
public void wound(int damage) {
    currentHitpoints -= damage;
}

/**
 * @return true if the fighter still has more than 0 hitpoints
 */
public boolean isAlive() {
    return currentHitpoints > 0;
}

/**
 * recover hitpoints (to a max of maxHitpoints
 * @param hitPoints
 */
public void recover(int hitPoints) {
    currentHitpoints += hitPoints;

    // dont go over maximum
    if (currentHitpoints > maxHitpoints) {
        currentHitpoints = maxHitpoints;
    }
    // message
    System.out.println("\t" + name + " recovers " + hitPoints + " to a current of " + currentHitpoints);
}

/**
 * @return is this a monster?
 */
public boolean isMonster() {
    return isMonster;
}

/**
 * @return how much money is left?
 */
public int getCurrentMoney() {
    return currentMoney;
}
}
```

---

**Weapon**

```
package stackoverflow.fight;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * Modeling the available weapons
 */
public enum Weapon {

BAT("Bat", 2, 4, 3), //
AXE("Axe", 4, 6, 6), //
SWORD("Sword", 6, 8, 10), //
CLAWS("Claws", 2, 15, -1), // cost=-1 indicating: not buyable!
;

private final String name;
private final int minDamage;
private final int maxDamage;
private final int cost;


private Weapon(String name, int minDamage, int maxDamage, int cost) {
    this.name = name;
    this.minDamage = minDamage;
    this.maxDamage = maxDamage;
    this.cost = cost;

}


public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public int getMinDamage() {
    return minDamage;
}

public int getMaxDamage() {
    return maxDamage;
}

public int getCost() {
    return cost;
}

/**
 * @return calculates the number of damage dealt with weapon
 */
public int rollDamage() {
    return getMinDamage()
            + Double.valueOf(
                    Math.random()
                            * (getMaxDamage() - getMinDamage())).intValue();
}

public static Weapon findByName(String name) {
    for (Weapon weapon : getBuyableWeapons()) {
        if (weapon.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
            return weapon;

        }
    }
    return null;
}

public static Set<Weapon> getBuyableWeapons() {
    Set<Weapon> buyableWeapons = new HashSet<Weapon>();

    for (Weapon weapon : Weapon.values()) {
        if (weapon.buyable()) {
            buyableWeapons.add(weapon);
        }
    }

    return buyableWeapons;
}

public boolean buyable() {
    return cost > 0;
}

public String toString() {
    return name + ", min:"+minDamage +", max:"+ maxDamage + ", cost:"+cost;
}

}
```

---

**Fight**

```
package stackoverflow.fight;

/**
 * implements the neverending fight between good and evil
 */
public class Fight {

private int roundCount = 1;

private final Opponent opponentOne;
private final Opponent opponentTwo;

/**
 * set up the fight between Opponents One and Two
 * 
 * @param opponentOne
 * @param opponentTwo
 */
public Fight(Opponent opponentOne, Opponent opponentTwo) {
    super();
    this.opponentOne = opponentOne;
    this.opponentTwo = opponentTwo;
}

/**
 * @return the fight is active while both opponents are alive
 */
public boolean isOngoing() {
    return opponentOne.isAlive() && opponentTwo.isAlive();
}

/**
 * perform the attack
 * 
 * @param a
 * @param b
 */
private void attack(Opponent a, Opponent b) {
    a.attack(b);
}

private void roundBasedSuccess() {
    // if Goodman survives round 2 print a message of encouragement
    if (opponentOne.isAlive() && roundCount == 2) {
        System.out
                .print("\tThis is encouraging. Goodman has lasted past round 2!");
        return;
    }

    // every 3 rounds, opponentA gains hitPoints
    if (opponentOne.isAlive() && roundCount % 3 == 0) {
        System.out
                .print("\tGoodman is as strong as Samson. He has lasted round "
                        + roundCount + " and still looks strong.");
        opponentOne.recover(10);
    }
}

/**
 * Command.F: Fight
 */
public void fight() {
    roundBasedSuccess();

    // who attacks first (0 or 1)
    switch (Double.valueOf(Math.random() * 2).intValue()) {
    case 0:
        System.out
                .println("\t" + opponentOne.getName() + " strikes first.");
        attack(opponentOne, opponentTwo);
        attack(opponentTwo, opponentOne);
        break;
    case 1:
        System.out.println("\t " + opponentTwo.getName()
                + " strikes first.");
        attack(opponentTwo, opponentOne);
        attack(opponentOne, opponentTwo);
        break;

    }

    // print message if still in the game
    if (opponentOne.isAlive()) {
        System.out.println("\t" + opponentOne.getName() + " has "
                + opponentOne.getCurrentHitpoints()
                + " points left. Not bad, Man! ");
    }

    if (opponentTwo.isAlive()) {
        System.out.println("\tWait, " + opponentTwo.getName()
                + " has a total of " + opponentTwo.getCurrentHitpoints()
                + " points and is still in the game");
    }

    System.out.println("This is the end of round " + roundCount++ + " "); // increase
                                                                            // roundCount
}

/**
 * Command.R: rest
 */
public void rest() {
    System.out.println("r: Opponents should rest (regaining 2 hitpoints");
    opponentOne.recover(2);
    opponentTwo.recover(2);
}

/**
 * Command.C: Status
 */
public void status() {
    System.out.println("\tChecking the status of the game: Round "
            + getRoundCount() + ": " + opponentOne.getName() + " has "
            + opponentOne.getCurrentHitpoints() + " points and "
            + opponentTwo.getName() + " has "
            + opponentTwo.getCurrentHitpoints() + " points\n");
}

/**
 * @return actual number of rounds
 */
public int getRoundCount() {
    return roundCount;
}

/**
 * @return title of the fight (A vs. B)
 */
public String getTitle() {
    return opponentOne.getName() + " vs. " + opponentTwo.getName()
            + " - Round " + roundCount + ": ";
}

/**
 * what happens if the fight is over
 */
public void end() {
    if (isOngoing()) {
        return; // Oops ... still alive
    }

    // opponentOne lost?
    if (!opponentOne.isAlive()) {
        System.out.println("\t" + opponentOne.getName()
                + "  you are out of the game! " + opponentTwo.getName()
                + " will take over the village. This is sad!");
        System.out.println("Game Over!");
    } else if (!opponentTwo.isAlive()) {
        System.out.println("\t" + opponentOne.getName()
                + " has been victorious");
        System.out.println("\t" + opponentTwo.getName()
                + " is dead. The people live!!!!");
        System.out.println("Game Over!");
    }

}

/**
 * Non-Monsters may switch weapons!
 * 
 * @param opponent
 * @param weapon
 */
public void buy(Opponent opponent, Weapon weapon) {
    if (opponent.isMonster()) {
        System.out.println("\tMonsters cannot buy weapons!");
        return;
    }

    // too expensive
    if (opponent.getCurrentMoney() < weapon.getCost()) {
        System.out.println("\t" + opponent.getName() + " has only " + opponent.getCurrentMoney() + " left. " + weapon.getName() + " costs " + weapon.getCost() + "!");
        return;
    }

    opponent.setWeapon(weapon);
}
    }
```

Comment: Jan, thanks a million. I will try it out to see how it works. I may have to ask further questions, if you do not mind

Comment: Jan, I am getting some error with the project. 

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method getBuyableWeapons() from the type Weapon refers to the missing type Set

 at stackoverflow.fight.Main.main(Main.java:62)

Comment: check your imports ... java.util.Set is a common framework class. Do you use an IDE (like Eclipse) or are you setting this up via console?

Comment: I got it. fix the problem. One more issue: when I select buy a weapon, then select the wrong weapon name, then select the right weapon I get his error 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at stackoverflow.fight.Fight.buy(Fight.java:170)
 at stackoverflow.fight.Main.main(Main.java:67)

Comment: Jan Galinski Could you help with the last java problem i just posted?

Answer (score 9):

Java is an Object Oriented Language. So you could model a class `Weapon` that has three attributes (`minDamage`, `maxDamage` and `cost`). You then create instances of that class

```
Weapon axe = new Weapon(2,4,3);
```

Later in your code where it comes to damage calculation, you can use `axe.getMinDamage()` and `axe.getMaxDamage()` to set the limits of your random function.

Comment: Jan, this is getting clearer to me. How do i add the value of MinDamage to the variable minDmg already in the statement?

I apologize, but  i am pretty new to java