# A better way of returning different types in Java

Tags: java, oop, return-value

```
public int attack(Bear bear)
{
    int newStamina=bear.getStamina() - 50;  
    bear.setStamina(newStamina);
    return bear.getStamina();
}
```

To extend on my fabulous Bear class, I've decided to implement an `attack`(!) method.

I have 2 instances of my bear object: Bear1 and Bear2.

In my head:

`Bear1.attack(Bear2);`

then my code gets `Bear2` current stamina value and takes away 50 from it, assigning it to the newStamina variable.

`Bear2` then gets passed this new stamina variable with the `setStamina` method.

I then return `Bear2`'s **current** stamina, after the brutal bear attack.

This works,  sort of. But I imagine there's a far better way.

Anyhoo. What I would like to do is, after:

`int newStamina=bear.getStamina() - 50;`

is:

```
if(newStamina <= 0)
{
    // the bear is dead!
}
```

Now my method `attack` returns an `int`, because if the bear doesn't die, it still has HP and I would like to output this current HP to the console or where ever.

If the bear is out of stamina, then I need to return something that signifies this.

What would you do? I can't return false, and I'm not sure that would work anyway.

Comment: I can't give you any pointers - Java doesn't have pointers, silly!!

Comment: But in reference to the first method, it can be simplified to a single return statement.  return bear.stamina-=50;

Comment: @Captain Giraffe - that makes sense I suppose, seems like I'm overcomplicating things. @user384706 - I think you understand my question better than I do!

Comment: You just need to remember that the private modifier applies to the class not the object. So since attack is a member of Bear it can access the private attributes of the argument bear. Glowcoder has a good point though.

Comment: Waaa, horrible idea imho. Don't misuse operations with side effects in such a way, it only makes the code less readable. The code is just fine and should hold up to most coding standards I've seen so far.

Comment: @Captain Giraffe - It make no sense to me that the attack's method return the stamina from the other bear. Plus, because you can do something doesn't mean that you should. You can access to the private attribute but it against all OOP philosophy to do it. The object have to provide its own method to get/set privates attributes

Comment: @Jean-Christophe this question is about the basic understanding and workings of the building blocks. Certainly not one concerning OO philosophy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good rule of thumb is **only modify instance variables inside set methods**. Doing this will keep your code more manageable.

```
/**
 * reduce this bears stamina by the given amount
 */
public void reduceStamina(int reduction) {
    setStamina(getStamina() - reduction);
}

public void isDead() {
    return getStamina() < 0;
}

public void attack(Bear otherBear) {
    otherBear.reduceStamina(50);
    if(otherBear.isDead()) {
        this.victoryDance();
    }
}
```

Comment: Fine code, except that it should be getStamine() <= 0 - a bear with 0HP should be dead as well ;)

Comment: @Voo depends on the game. Actually some games you don't die until -20 HP or something similar. Between 0 and -20 you're merely unconscious. In any event, implementation details are left as EFTR.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this - returning an object instead of an int.

```
public Bear attack(Bear bear)
{
        int newStamina=bear.getStamina() - 50;  
        bear.setStamina(newStamina);
        if(newStamina<=0)
        {
            bear.isDead=true;
        }
        return bear;
}

// in main
while(Bear2.isDead==false)
{
            Bear1.attack(Bear2);
            System.out.println(Bear2.getStamina());
}

if(Bear2.isDead)
{
    System.out.println(Bear2.getName() + " is dead :(");
}
```

that seems to work..! will be interested to see other solutions.

Comment: In this code, you don't use the return value at all, so you could simply let it be `void`, and ommit the return line.

Answer (score 0):

From an OOP point of view, I would separate the Object "Bear" with its attribute "stamina" from the Object "Fight", which holds two bears and handles the attack and "still alive". I published some examples to a quite similar question some weeks ago: [help with changing arrays into individual variables in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143866/help-with-changing-arrays-into-individual-variables-in-java/5143936#5143936)

Comment: From an OOP point of view, everything should be an object. Attack which inherit from Action, Bear inherit from Animal which inherit from Living and.... but as I see, it might be too abstract for the this question

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `int` you could return an `Integer`. In case the bear is dead you could return `null`.

```
public Integer attack(Bear attackedBear){
    Integer resultingStamina;
    ...
    if(resultingStamina<=0){
        resultingStamina = null;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

that may do the job for you :

```
public int attack(Bear bear)
    {
        int newStamina=bear.getStamina() - 50;  
        bear.setStamina(newStamina);
        if(newStamina<=0)
        {
          bear.isDead=true;
        }
        return bear
    }
```

and in your main you verify if the returned bear still has stamina if not GAME OVER ...

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main()
{    
      Bear b1 = new bear();
      Bear b2 = new bear();
      while(!b2.IsDead())
      {
            b1.attack(b2);
            System.out.println(b2.getStamina());
      }

      System.out.println(b2.getName() + " is dead :(");
}



public class Bear
{
    private int _stamina;

    public int getStamina()
    {
          return _stamina;
    }

    public bool Isdead()
    {
          return _stamina == 0;
    }

    public void sufferAttack(int dommage)
    {
      _stamina = dommage > _stamina ? 0:(_stamina - dommage);
    }

    public void attack(Bear b)
    {
         b.sufferAttack(50);
    }
}
```

Now the reason.

First of all. Never expose internals attributes.Following the Demeters law, Nothing but the object itself should be able to change his current state.

Second, It make no sense to return an int(the stamina of the b2). B1 attack b2 and it a b1's method that return b2 stamina ? No. B1 have the responsibility to attack b1 and b2 the responsibility to suffer the attack and to provide a way to expose his current state.

You have to think about the responsibility of every class (and every method) before returning any kind of value.

When a bear attack I expect another bear to suffer an attack and when a bear suffer an attack I expect it to loose some stamina.

Comment: FYI `while(b2.isDead==false)` can be expressed as `while(!b2.isDead)`

Comment: If the bear doesn't die by an attack, you may never notice, because you tried to define dead as stamina == 0. It's safer to say "stamina <= 0", so when you implement the "getHitByCar()" method, you don't have to think of zeroing exactly again.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this:

```
return new Pair <Integer, Boolean> (newStamina, bear.isAlive());
```

Not so good: return 2 ints, one representing the bool:

```
return new int [] {newStamina, bear.isAlive() ? 1 : 0};
```

Comment: both are bad style. Whenever you have to deal with multible return values, you should ask yourself: where is the flaw in my design?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but returning a `Pair<>` is a bad idea, and a lot of people agree: http://tech.puredanger.com/2010/03/31/do-we-want-a-java-util-pair/

Comment: I didn't recommend that design, I'm not even sure I understood the question right. But every Object which isn't a simple int, double, char is a kind of combined object. If you don't like OOP, you shouldn't use Java in the first place. If one has a more concrete thing than just this Pair, he should use it.

Comment: @glowcoder: Did you ever work with a ResultSet (jdbc)? What else is it, if not a tuple? But I will read that text; maybe I'm missing here something.

Comment: You should not use Pair in OO language. There isn't any pair in real life. BTW, I'm the downvoter.

Comment: @User yes, I have. You are correct in a sense. But that is only because of the dynamic nature of your access layer. When it comes to classes in your design, Pair is vastly inferior to making your own class. The whole point of classes is to make a real-world-like model for your program, and the whole point of Pair is so you don't have to make those simple classes which is contrary to the point of classes.

Comment: So the article argues with 'feeling dirty' and other people arguing against Pair, but partly, like Joshua Bloch, for a more general Tuple-solution. And his article is a reaction to a lot of people using them, which he denounces as 'fans'. But at least you had a link for your critique, while Jan has only dogma.

Comment: @Stas: There aren't ResultSets in real life, nor Vectors, Strings and Integers (not, as implemented in Java). Who is interested in real life? If you prefer Boilerplate, write a class BearHealthAndStatus or something, and use that.

Comment: @User.. Yeah. You can think that I prefer boilerplate.. But. hey! It's Java.

Comment: BearHealthAndStatus is then just a different name. For a long living, far travelling object that might be a difference which makes a difference. From the 5 lines of code we'd been shown, I wouldn't decide so.